# How to match SQL Queries in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex

I want to match same type of SQL Queries with different condition values,

For example :

```
SELECT * FROM Customer Where Age > 20 AND Age < 40

SELECT * FROM Customer Where Age > 30 AND Age < 50
```

Both of the above queries are the same except the values in the WHERE condition (20, 40, 30 and 50). I want to identify such queries. It should work with HAVING as well. It should work for any value type in the condition (int, varchar, date etc).

Basically I want to write a C# function to which I can pass 2 queries and it should return true if both queries are the same except the values in the exclusion condition.

Another Example :

```
SELECT Employees.LastName, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM (Orders
INNER JOIN Employees
ON Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID)
GROUP BY LastName
HAVING COUNT(Orders.OrderID) > 10;

SELECT Employees.LastName, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM (Orders
INNER JOIN Employees
ON Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID)
GROUP BY LastName
HAVING COUNT(Orders.OrderID) > 50;

SELECT Employees.FirstName, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM (Orders
INNER JOIN Employees
ON Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID)
GROUP BY FirstName
HAVING COUNT(Orders.OrderID) > 50;
```

When I pass 1st and 2nd queries it should return true, but false for 2nd and 3rd.

I tried with Regular Expressions, but how to find where the parameter located? It can be anywhere.

Is it possible to do it with SqlScriptDom? How? I am using SqlScriptDom to get the table names from the SQL query, but how to get parameters?

Comment: Parameterised queries?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "matching queries?"  I'm not understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Siyual Please look at the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I don't mean to pick on your language but I think it's kind of important here.  The queries in your example don't have parameters.  They have exclusion criteria in a WHERE clause. It sounds like what you're trying to do is compare the text of two queries for everything except the WHERE clause.  ANSI SQL and T-SQL both follow the same convention that in a SELECT query the WHERE clause comes after the FROM clause and before any GROUP BY, HAVING or ORDER BY clause.  So you could pull it out and compare it that way if you were going to just analyze the text of the code.  One issue you might think about though is that SQL often provides subtly different ways of accomplishing the same thing.  For example, if in your examples, you had <= and >= instead of < and > you could use the BETWEEN operator.

I think you probably could use the SqlScriptDom to do what you want but I'm not good enough with that to help really.

Comment: Please see the updated question. Is there any libraries already does this?

Comment: I think it would be possible to write that with the Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.   I'm not an expert.  Look here  https://the.agilesql.club/blog/Ed-Elliott/2015-11-07/Get-Started-With-The-ScriptDom